# Issue with WhatsApp's downloaded videos

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, video

I have got a new Moto G4 Plus. When I tap to play a downloaded video message, I tap it many times but it doesn't play. However, when I go back to all chats and return to the message, it then opens finely with one tap only. Please tell what's with it?

Comment: Try updating the Google Photo app from Google Play, or install it.

Comment: First reboot your mobile and try to uninstall and reinstall it back...

Comment: It is already updated.

Comment: @VigneshReddy  I often hate doing thus, but still will try and update you.